# Improved tab in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, indentation

I want to override the bad default tabbing scheme in emacs so that it will work like most other editors (eclipse, notepad++). I want to set it so that regardless of mode, tab will insert a tab, and pressing enter will keep me at my current tab depth.

I tried this, but it does nothing:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop)
(setq default-tab-width 4) ;; 8 is way too many
```

Comment: Some major modes may override this. Can you say more about you environment?

Comment: I am really aiming to get it for all environments.  It really annoys me when it decides that it knows better than me, and refuses to allow me to indent as i please.  eg. in apache config it allows me 1, 8 char tab, and no further.  the elisp mode is sane, but inconsistent with the usual.

Comment: If it only allows one 8-character tab, the fix is to change *that*, change what its tab stops are. (Or change the indent function.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make the Enter key take you to the next line and indent it automatically, you can put

```
(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
```

in your `.emacs`. [Or you can hit `C-j` instead of Enter.] Once you have that, you'll never need to insert tabs manually, because Emacs automatically indents a new line to extra depth after an opening brace, etc. If you do want to change the indentation, you can hit TAB until it takes you to the right indentation, then start typing from there. [And when you type a closing brace, Emacs is smart enough to take that brace one indentation level backwards.]

You should remove the `(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop)` for this to work.

Answer (score 6):

Many major modes override the `TAB` binding, for example cc-mode binds `TAB` to `'c-indent-to-column`.

The `'global-set-key` that is suggested does nothing as almost every major mode has overridden the `TAB`.

One trick that might work for you is to copy the approach that `'pabbrev` uses, and define a global minor mode that has the `TAB` bound.  You could do that like so:

```
(defvar just-tab-keymap (make-sparse-keymap) "Keymap for just-tab-mode")
(define-minor-mode just-tab-mode
  "Just want the TAB key to be a TAB"
  :global t :lighter " TAB" :init-value 0 :keymap just-tab-keymap
  (define-key just-tab-keymap (kbd "TAB") 'indent-for-tab-command))
```

However, this disables all `TAB` completion.  You'll probably get best results by overriding each of the major-modes one by one (so as to avoid mussing up `TAB` completion).

Comment: Actually, very few major modes re-bind TAB, and even fewer should do it.  They should rely on `indent-line-function` instead.

Answer (score 4):

This bugged me, too, when I first started using Emacs.  I've come to love it, though.  If I want to indent appropriately, I hit `<tab>;` if I want to insert a literal tab, I hit `M-i` (Meta and 'i' or <Alt>-<i> in some parlances) which is bound to `tab-to-tab-stop`.

Answer (score 3):

I think trey jackson's answer is probably what you want, except possibly use `'self-insert-command` instead of `'indent-for-tab-command`. I personally prefer emacs' default behavior, but `self-insert-command` does what it says instead of trying to do anything fancy like make sure your code is well-formatted.

The few times I actually *want* to insert a tab (not indent) I press M-i.

Comment: `M-i`!!!! Sir, you have personally saved me from carpal tunnel... `Control-q <TAB>` was starting to take a toll on my left hand.

Comment: `M-i` is `tab-to-tab-stop` which only inserts a tab character if `indent-tabs-mode` is true. You may well find `C-q C-i` easier to type than `C-q TAB`, however (especially if you have the Caps Lock key configured as a Ctrl key).

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in this minor mode I created at http://github.com/vohrta/regtab.

It makes it so that when you press the tab key either a tab character (if indent-tabs-mod is not nil) or tab-width spaces will be placed at point. The mode is also capable of handling what you may consider regular behavior on a region of selected text and shift-tabbing to remove tabs at the beginning of the line (or set of lines).

You can enable or disable it at any time by pressing M-x regtab-mode.

Answer (score 1):

`C-j` does the newline + indent functionality that you want out of pressing Enter.