# completely lucid tabs and spaces in emacs?

Tags: emacs, indentation

The title of my question is a reference to [sane tabs in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344966/sane-tab-in-emacs).

Basically what I want is to globally set tabs and indention to work in
some uniform way. I feel like emacs is so much better than TextMate 
or BBEdit but really the way they handle indention is simple and great
for my purposes. In emacs if you use some tab/space scheme that's 
different than the scheme enforced by a minor mode you use you're in 
trouble.

When I press enter I'd like to be moved to the next line indented to 
the right place using tabs. If I can have my cake and eat it too I'd
like to be indented using spaces if the rest of the file is composed 
that way.

I've tried these also:

[doing tabs in emacs](http://robrohan.com/2006/10/25/doing-tabs-in-emacs/)

[force emacs to use tabs](http://hurring.com/scott/howto/emacs_force_tabs/)

Thanks to anyone who can help me achieve this.

-Mike

Comment: I ended up needing to combine a bunch of different snippets from the articles mentioned in my question and other bits from the answers below. I'm apprehensive to accept just one answer because none were complete solutions for me. Of course this may say more about my question than it does about the answers. Thanks to everyone. If anyone cares to know what I ended up with I can post it here, just let me know. -Mike

Comment: Can you please post what worked for you. I am also looking for a way to have the cake and eat it too :). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps `(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)` is what you want?
(Or `reindent-then-newline-and-indent` if that's available, or you could just hit `C-j` instead of the Enter key.)

Answer (score 2):

For this part of your question:

> If I can have my cake and eat it too I'd like to be indented using spaces if the rest of 
>   the file is composed that way.

does this do what you want?

```
(defun dtrt-indent ()
  (setq indent-tabs-mode  
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (search-forward "\t" nil t))))
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'dtrt-indent)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'dtrt-indent)
; etc for all modes you care about
```

So if there's a tab anywhere in the buffer, indent using tabs; if there is no tab, indent using spaces.

Comment: FWIW, rather than guess, I declare settings like this with eproject:

http://wiki.github.com/jrockway/eproject/project-attributes

Answer (score 0):

if you do your setup as described:

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq tab-width 4) ;; 8 is way too many
(setq default-tab-width 4) ;; 8 is way too many
(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
```

The `indent-tabs-mode` thing will tell emacs to create your indentation by using TABS and SPACES to make up the desired indentation (defined by the individual mode). This means, if you want to have a TAB inserted instead of TABS/SPACES you need to configure your mode to use `tab-width` as indentation.

For example if you use `c-mode` and select `cc-mode` as indentation style (select with `C-c .`) which uses 4 as indentation value, `newline-and-indent` will insert spaces.

To conclude:

1. Check that your mode uses `tab-width` as indentation
2. Check that your mode doesn't overwride `indent-tabs-mode` (`python-mode` seems to do this)

Although I personally don't like TABS good luck on your journey :)

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy is to convince your programming mode of choice to
 indent things the way you like.  This is generally very easy; I am
 picky about indentation and my emacs always does the right thing
 automatically.  (That means that "indent-region" also always does
 what I want, which is very convenient.)