# Special indentation style for Emacs and javascript

Tags: javascript, emacs, indentation, js2-mode

Running js2-mode for emacs, I need a way to alter the indentation style to look like this:

```
var test = ["Test",
    "Asdfasdf"
];
```

Rather than the default:

```
var test = ["Test",
            "Asdfasdf"
           ];
```

I've tried to modify stuff like `c-offsets-alist` but it doesn't take. Any suggestions?

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906228/emacs-problematic-javascript-indentation), but it's 5 years old and requires overriding code. Is there a more elegant way to have the below conform to this?

```
AngularApp.run(["Stuff", "Websocket", "$http", "Other", "More", "Etc", "AndSoOn",
                function(s, w, $http, o, m, e, a) {
                    //code
               }
              ]);
```

And have it look like this:

```
AngularApp.run(["Stuff", "Websocket", "$http", "Other", "More", "Etc", "AndSoOn",
    function(s, w, $http, o, m, e, a) {
        //code
    }
]);
```

Comment: emacs.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask

Comment: thanks, I'll ask there too

Comment: No. Please do not ask there too. Either place is OK - choose *one*. Your choice can be based on the potential set of readers and answerers. Since you asked there also, please delete one of the questions, here or there. Thx.

Comment: ah, deleted the other one.