# Emacs tabs strange behaviour .conf files

Tags: emacs

Edit: Fresh install of emacs (emacs version from M-x emacs-version: GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.21) of 2017-09-22, modified by Debian)
I had originall had emacs version 47.0 (that was from dpkg -l emacs which showed that as a metapackage)

Server was new and never had it before.

I am not an emacs guru. I don't fiddle too much and I can just get around in it.

I set
tab-width 4
indent-tabs-mode nil

I tried it before setting tab-stop-list and then setting it to nil and to "4 8 12" and to "0 4 8" but it didn't change the behaviour I describe below. In fact none of the settings I changed seemed to affect anything for this.

I then tried searching for the problem, and I tried everything mentioned (c-basic-offset, standard-indent, etc) nothing seemed to help.

I am simply trying to edit conf files.

This is an example

settings.conf:

```
setting name {
    param1=1
    param2={
        s1="test"
        s2=5
    }

}
```

however when I hit the tab key the behaviour is all over the place.

```
[a1]
setting name {
[a2]
    param1=1
    param2={
[a3]
        s1="test"
        s2=5
    }
}
```

- in [a1] - tab is 4 spaces - I can hit  all day and its fine - perfect
- in [a2] hitting tab from the start of the line:
  first tab key inserts a tab (size of 4 spaces but backspace deletes it as a whole) and then 3 spaces
  second tab key inserts 3 tabs (each the size of 4 spaces)
  third tab key inserts 2 tabs (4 spaces size) and then 3 spaces
- in [a3] hitting  from the start of the line:
  first tab key inserts a tab (size 4 spaces)
  second tab key inserts a tab (4 spaces) and then 3 individual spaces
  third tab key seems to move forward 1 space and converts the 3 individual spaces from before and its newly added 1 space to a tab character as backspace deletes a size of 4 spaces in 1 go

I have no idea what is going on and except for those settings mentioned above that I change through M-x customize I haven't touched anything else at all.
Only other thing I can say is I am running emacs on Ubuntu 18.04 (edit from 20.04 - my mistake, sorry) on a server I ssh too.

By C-h k  I get the following:
TAB runs the command indent-for-tab-command (found in global-map),
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘indent.el’.

It is bound to TAB.

(indent-for-tab-command &optional ARG)

Indent the current line or region, or insert a tab, as appropriate.
This function either inserts a tab, or indents the current line,
or performs symbol completion, depending on ‘tab-always-indent’.
The function called to actually indent the line or insert a tab
is given by the variable ‘indent-line-function’.

If a prefix argument is given, after this function indents the
current line or inserts a tab, it also rigidly indents the entire

It works in 'text-mode" but I don't want to switch to 'text-mode' (in which it works) as I like the highlighting it does.

*Edit (from comment): 
I need to edit files that are listed as .conf and .cnf. There are hundreds of them in total. Some are for internal applications. The .cnf file are for nagios, and the .conf files are for icinga

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of file is `settings.conf`?  `.conf` files typically do not have that kind of syntax, so your problem will undoubtedly be that the major mode Emacs is using is not appropriate.  There is a pretty wide variety of possibilities for files with that extension, but nested `{` ... `}` blocks is very unusual in my experience, and I *suspect* that none of the Emacs `conf` options would support that.

Comment: Fixed version info - got the server release wrong, we got two at near the same time and the other was 20.04 so I had made assumptions about this one.

Comment: I need to edit files that are listed as .conf and .cnf.
There are hundreds of them in total. Some are for internal applications. The .cnf file are for nagios, and the .conf files are for icinga.

Comment: A quick search turned up http://michael.orlitzky.com/code/nagios-mode.xhtml for nagios files.  Apparently icinga is a fork of nagios, so maybe it works for those files as well?

Comment: Obviously Emacs is pre-configured to use `conf-mode` for `.conf` files.  You could *clobber* that with `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.conf\\'" . nagios-mode))` after which it would use `nagios-mode` for any `.conf` file.  Otherwise you'll need some reliable way of distinguishing them, either by file path or by buffer contents.

Comment: Nagios mode isn't that helpful. Nagios is about 20% of the files I need to edit. Icinga about 35% and the rest are for internal applications. 
ALl the .conf files are very similar to this, nested curly brackets. I guess the internal applications are json format if that helps. I can probably look at some path filtering for choosing the mode, I suppose. Vim highlights them neatly enough and has no problems, but I like Emacs better for my workflow and I find it easier to jump around files with it.

Comment: I would settle for simply disabling any indenting and tab was just 4 spaces every time. The systems I have to work on for this won't be do anything else with emacs (at least for me).
I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344966/improved-tab-in-emacs
But it didn't help enough. The behaviour changed slightly, so that rather than the tab characters as mentioned in the original problem it does use straight spaces but it still does the odd spacing (jumping 7 spaces, or 12 spaces instead of a tab and 3 spaces or 3 tabs and so on)

Comment: I ended up adding this to my emacs config: (global-set-key "\t" 'tab-to-tab-stop). It is a bit overkill, but keeps the highlighting and gives me the base functionality I want.
I would like to keep this open in the hopes that someone has a more elegant solution or whatnot, but thanks everyone for the suggestions. I will at least into the nagios-mode and into the major/minor modes a bit more.

Comment: If the files are JSON then presumably `js-mode` will work?  You're on an oldish version of Emacs, so I'm not able to test it.  Failing that, perhaps something like https://github.com/joshwnj/json-mode does the trick?